# Como diferenciar tipo de dispositivo a partir do IP?

Tags: java, socket, redes, ip, host

Como saber que tipo de dispositivo está a usar um IP?

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de validar se um IP pertence a um computador, a um dispositivo móvel, etc.

Isto é diferenciar os tipos do dispositivo a partir do IP.

Tenho interesse de fazer isso em Java.

Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Você tem duas boas respostas, uma falando do Número de IP (a do Victor) e a outra falando do Protocolo conhecido como IP (a do ederwander), cuja interpretação independe do número propriamente dito. A qual das duas coisas a pergunta se refere, o número ou o protocolo?

Comment: Realmente a pergunta ficou aberta para interpretações como o @Bacco disse, quando li a questão eu apenas interpretei que qualquer IP trafegando poderá ser analisado e classificado, imagina que eu vou até sua casa conecto na sua rede Wifi e não conheça nenhum dos outros ips da sua rede, eu posso usar um scan descobrir quais ips estão vivos e aplicar fingerprint neles enviando pacotes e analisando os retornos, mas agora realmente fiquei na dúvida se era isso que vc gostaria de saber huauahuahu

Comment: @ederwander como a pergunta é ambígua, considero que no momento das respostas tanto você quanto o Victor responderam corretamente. Só comentei, pq apesar das duas terem informações que aparentam conflitantes, na verdade são complementares, pois os aspectos abordados são diferentes, aí achei por bem deixar isso claro :)

Answer (score 7):

Vamos lá rapaz, a maioria disse que não é possível, mas na realidade é sim!

Não sei se você vai utilizar isso para o bem ou se quer dar um de hacker por aí, o que você vai fazer com esse tipo de informação fica a cargo de sua consciência e de todos que vão ler!

Graças a peculiaridades na implementação da pilha TCP/IP de diferentes fornecedores é possível analisar e identificar diferentes sistemas operacionais/dispositivos.

Para entender como isso funciona é importante que você conheça a estrutura de um pacote IP:

[image: estrutura de pacotes TCP/IP]

Olha só quanta informação um pacote TCP carrega, não vou tratar de cada parâmetro isso é um pouco extenso, o que é importante pra você saber é que algumas destas informações  mudam de SO para SO e é possível analisar isso utilizando técnicas de análise de tráfego.

Isso pode ser feito de maneira passiva ou ativa:

1. **Ativo** - Seu equipamento (PC, etc) envia pacotes para o IP que você deseja e analisa a resposta.
2. **Passivo** - Só intercepta os pacotes que trafegam na rede (sniffers).

Uma maneira bem rudimentar é analisar os campos Time to Live (TTL) e Window!

**TTL** - Tempo máximo que os pacotes podem demorar antes de serem destruídos (pode ser observado na figura da estrutura do pacote IP na parte vermelha).

**window** - Tamanho da janela de recepção (pode ser observado na figura da estrutura do pacote IP na parte amarela).

Veja como determinados padrões para esses dois campos podem te dizer Sistemas Operacionais diferenciados só analisando o retorno dos pacotes:

**Linux (Kernel 2.4 e 2.6)**

- Time To Live = 64
- TCP Window Size = 5840

**Google Linux**

- Time To Live = 64
- TCP Window Size = 5720

**FreeBSD**

- Time To Live = 64
- TCP Window Size = 65535

**Windows XP**

- Time To Live = 128
- TCP Window Size = 65535

**Windows Vista e 7 (Windows Server 2008)**

- Time To Live = 128
- TCP Window Size = 8192

**iOS 12.4 ou Roteadores Cisco**

- Time To Live = 255
- TCP Window Size = 4128

OK, agora você tem ideia de como isso é possível, imagine agora ao invés de analisar só dois campos, analisar um conjunto maior, definir e observar os padrões e assim conseguir uma maior consistência e acertos. Pois bem, isso é possível, com 67 bits de análise você irá possuir uma assinatura bem confiável:

1. Tamanho do pacote inicial - Utilizando os valores dos Campo **IHL** e
   **Total Length** é possível saber o tamanho inicial do pacote (16
   bits).
2. Valor do campo Time to Live (8 bits).
3. Valor do campo Window (16 bits).
4. Tamanho máximo do segmento (16 bits) - No campo **TCP Options** pode conter a informação que define o tamanho máximo de recepção de segmento, essa informação é enviada na comunicação inicial, se esse parâmetro não existir qualquer tamanho de segmento é permitido.
5. Window scaling value (8 bits) - No campo **TCP Options** pode conter informações permitindo o aumento de tamanho dos pacotes recebidos.
6. "don't fragment" flag (1 bit) - No campo **Fragmento Offset** pode conter informações de fragmentações ou não.
7. "sackOK" flag (1 bit) - No campo **TCP Options** pode conter informações sobre como os pacotes são retransmitidos em caso de percas, diz se os recebimentos seletivos são permitidos ou não.
8. "nop" flag (1 bit) - mais uma opção definida no campo **TCP Options**, o comprimento do cabeçalho TCP precisa ser múltiplo de 4. No entanto nem sempre isso vai acontecer, quando ocorrer essa disparidade é preciso enviar alguns NOPs (1 bit ou mais) para ajustar o tamanho do cabeçalho e dependendo onde estes NOPs são adicionados e se estão no início ou fim ao longo das opções, podemos identificar padrões de determinados SO's.

Se você somar todos os BITS destes 8 campos terá 67 bits de informações que variam e se comportam de maneira diferente, agora você pode construir um Fingerprint (impressão digital) e traçar os padrões de comportamento que cada sistema operacional possui na rede!

Comment: Mas o TTL não pode ser alterado?

Comment: @diegofm praticamente qualquer valor pode ser modificado, vc deve fazer isso dentro do SO e mudar os defaults, no windows é possível alterar via registro e no linux via sysctl, mas gerando um fingerprint de 67 bits não vai importar se 1 ou 2 parâmetros não forem "padrões" todos os outros campos restantes ainda te dará informações suficientes, por isso disse que só pegar as infos do TTL e Window é rudimentar, lembre-se fingerprints devem ser capazes de reconhecer dados padrões mesmo que determinados desvios aconteçam ou seja um dado ou outro pode ser diferente ou faltando...

Comment: Nisso você supõe que o dispositivo realize conexões TCP e que as realize conforme o sistema operacional faz por padrão, o que pode ou não ser uma suposição razoável.

Answer (score 2):

Não, isso que você quer não é possível.

O número do IP é apenas e tão somente isso, um número. E na prática, qualquer dispositivo pode pegar qualquer número de IP.

Por exemplo, vamos supor que na minha casa eu tenha um DHCP com endereço de rede 192.168.55.0 e que o meu primo também tenha um DHCP do mesmo jeito na casa dele.

Então, eu conecto o meu computador na minha rede e obtenho o IP 192.168.55.1. Depois conecto um tablet, e ele obtém o 192.168.55.2. Depois coloco um celular, e ele obtém o 192.168.55.3.

Já o meu primo, liga o tablet primeiro, que pega o IP 192.168.55.1. Depois liga o celular, que pega o 192.168.55.2 e por último um notebook no 192.168.55.3.

Observe que com isso, o 192.168.55.1 é um computador na minha rede, mas é um tablet na rede do meu primo. O 192.168.55.2 é um tablet na minha rede, mas um celular na do meu primo. E o 192.168.55.3 é um celular na minha rede e um notebook na do meu primo.

Enfim, somente usando o número do IP, você não consegue obter nenhuma informação útil para se determinar o dispositivo de que se trata. Assim sendo, você vai precisar de alguma outra coisa diferente para conseguir fazer o que você quer.

Comment: Conheces alguma outra forma de saber dessas informações na rede

Comment: @DanielCostaDC Se o dispositivo tiver um navegador, quando ele acessar alguma URL que você tenha controle, ao analisar o cabeçalho "`user-agent`", você pode tentar deduzir essa informação (não é garantido, mas pode funcionar). Obviamente, isso pressupõe que ninguém esteja manipulando esse cabeçalho para contornar alguma restrição ou realizar alguma atividade maliciosa (o que é possível, mas incomum). Outra possibilidade é você instalar um software específico em cada dispositivo para te dar essa informação, mas isso pressupõe que você possa fazer isso e que ninguém vai tentar burlar.

Comment: @VictorStafusa sim é possível :-)

Answer (score 0):

O mais proximo do que você esta procurando seria utilizar o MAC Address da maquina, porem ate mesmo o MAC não é totalmente confiável, pois você pode identificar apenas o fabricante, e não o modelo em si.

Caso queira da uma lida mais a fundo no que o Mac pode fazer:
https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endere%C3%A7o_MAC

Espero ter ajudado com sua pesquisa.